# grep tab separated string in perl

Tags: perl, grep

I am trying to grep tab separated numbers (eg 1\t3) in an array something like

```
@data= 
1 3
2 3
1 3
3 3
```

the idea behind the code is something like this

```
    #!usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;

   my @data = ( "1\t3", "2\t3", "1\t3", "3\t3", );
    for (my $i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
        for (my $j=0;$j<4_size;$j++) {
        my $pattern= "$i\t$j";
        my @count=grep(/$pattern/,@data); 
        undef $pattern;
        print "$pattern\tcount\n";
        }
        }
```

hoping for output something like

1st and second column: pattern

3nd column : count of total matches

```
1 1
1 2
1 3 2
2 1
2 3 1
3 1 
3 2
3 3 1
```

but the output is null for some reasons,
I am recently learnt and finding it very intriguing.
any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think that's the code you actually ran. I get : `Misplaced _ in number at x.pl line 7.
Bareword found where operator expected at x.pl line 7, near "4_size" (Missing operator before size?)
No such class data at x.pl line 5, near "my data"
syntax error at x.pl line 5, near "my data;"
syntax error at x.pl line 7, near "4_size"
syntax error at x.pl line 7, near "++) "
Global symbol "@data" requires explicit package name at x.pl line 9.
syntax error at x.pl line 10, near "$pattern;"
Execution of x.pl aborted due to compilation errors.` Please provide code that actually produces the problem!

Comment: yes right.. i have mentioned just the idea behind it..

Comment: The quality of answers you get is proportional to the effort you put in to formulating a question.

Comment: yes i totally agree.. i edited the question again..this was my fist q on stackexchange.. i will remember this next time.. thanks. :D

Comment: Adding a disclaimer to your question helps no one. Please just *publish the real code*.

Comment: its the same.. there's nothing i can do better.. im learning.. anyways  Lee Duhem's code (below) worked for me.. so please suppose that i was trying the same..

Comment: You wrote a program that had the problem *"the output is null for some reasons"*. Please let us see it. If you had written Lee's answer then you wouldn't be asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. Here is a working version:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = ( "1\t3", "2\t3", "1\t3", "3\t3", );

foreach my $i (1 .. 3) {
    foreach my $j (1 .. 3) {
        my $pattern = "$i\t$j";
        my $count = grep(/$pattern/, @data);
        print $pattern . ($count ? "\t$count\n" : "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `$data[3] = "(\t3"`? Why are you first returning all the matches from `grep`, only to make a scalar assignment? You know you can interpolate variables into a pattern, so why the extra variable?

Comment: Note that `11<tab>3` will be counted as `1<tab>3`. `/^$pattern\z/` fixes this.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for your improvement.

Comment: Or, better, `grep { $_ eq $pattern } @data`

Answer (score 1):

The code below:

1. Does not crash if input contains unexpected characters (e.g., `'('`)
2. Only counts exact matches for the sequences of digits on either side of `"\t"`.
3. Matches lines that might have been read from a file or `__DATA__` section without using [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) using [`\R`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#CHARACTER-CLASSES).

--

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl

 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my @data = ( "1\t3", "2\t3", "(\t4", "1\t3", "3\t3", "11\t3" );

 for my $i (1 .. 3) {
     for my $j (1 .. 3) {
         my $pattern = "$i\t$j";
         my $count = grep  /\A\Q$pattern\E\R?\z/, @data;
         print join("\t", $pattern, $count ? $count : ''), "\n";
     }
 }
```

Output:

```
1   1
1   2
1   3   2
2   1
2   2
2   3   1
3   1
3   2
3   3   1
```